# WPF Margin as offset weirdness

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using the Margin property on ItemsControl inside a grid to act like their top left corner (x,y) offset. Each item in the ItemsControl is a DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="NodeTemplate">
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <TransformGroup x:Key="Rotation">
            <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Path=AngleOnXYPlane}" />
        </TransformGroup>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!-- icon on map -->
    <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="6" Height="6" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5" RenderTransform="{StaticResource Rotation}" >
        <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
            <Rectangle Fill="DarkGray" Width="3" Height="3" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

And here where I use it:

```
<Grid Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Name="ControlBar" Height="32"/>
        <RowDefinition Name="MarkerArea" Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- NodeArea -->
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- NodeArea -->
        <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                <ZoomAndPan:ZoomAndPanControl
                                x:Name="ZoomAndPanControl"
                                MouseDoubleClick="zoomAndPanControl_MouseDoubleClick"
                                MouseDown="zoomAndPanControl_MouseDown"
                                MouseUp="zoomAndPanControl_MouseUp"
                                MouseMove="zoomAndPanControl_MouseMove"
                                MouseWheel="zoomAndPanControl_MouseWheel"
                                cal:Message.Attach="[Event Loaded] = [Action ZoomAndPanLoaded($source)]">
                    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Width="{Binding Path=CanvasWidth}" Height="{Binding Path=CanvasHeight}">
                        <!-- Nodes -->
                        <ItemsControl x:Name="NodeCanvas" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NodeTemplate}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <Grid />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">
                                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{Binding Path=Position, Converter={StaticResource marginConverter}}" />
                                </Style>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </Grid>
                </ZoomAndPan:ZoomAndPanControl>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

The margin converter looks like this:

```
public class MarginConverter : DependencyObject, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is double)
        {
            double inputValue = (double)value;
            return new Thickness(inputValue, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        else if (value is float)
        {
            double inputValue = (double)((float)value);
            return new Thickness(inputValue, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        else if (value is int)
        {
            double inputValue = (double)((int)value);
            return new Thickness(inputValue, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        else if (value is Point)
        {
            Point pt = (Point)value;
            return new Thickness(pt.X, pt.Y, 0, 0);
        }

        return new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
    }
}
```

Question: How come their X,Y coordinate is always HALF of what their actual coordinates? Any insights?

Thanks

Comment: If your goal is absolute positioning, you would better use a Canvas as ItemsPanel and set the Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top attached properties in the ItemContainerStyle. For your solution with a Grid you would at least also have to set the item's HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment to Left and Top.

Comment: Because I have a ZoomAndPanControl that wraps the Grid housing the ItemsControl, if I were to place HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment to Left and Top, panning would not work since the top left corner would be the max you can pan. Therefore, I would like to put my things in the center.